# PhpStorm 2016.x hinting behavior for objects in the top level namespace

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a personal PHP framework that I maintain and use for most of the work I do. Currently in the main `index.php` file, I have the following code which provides access to the core application class from anywhere in the project:

```
/**
 * @return App
 */
function app() {
    // Returns the main App class instance.
}
```

It is properly annotated with PHPDoc so that when used, any `@property-read` declarations or other public members of `App` will be available in the code hint:

[image]

Up until the new release, PhpStorm would *always* be aware of the contents of `App` and provide this code hint. Now however, the code hint doesn't work unless you are in the same namespace as `App` (a top level namespace) or explicitly `use App` or prefix all calls to `app()` as `\app()`.

What's weirder is that even though the code hint isn't available outside of the top level, the quick documentation utility is perfectly aware that `app()` returns an `App` and links to the correct definition for `App`:

[image]

I've tried marking `public` as a "Sources Root" and updating my `composer.json` to include `public` in the `autoload/psr4` block for `""` with no change:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4" : {
        "": ["public/", "app/src/"]
    }
}
```

At this stage I'm not sure whether:

1. This is a bug with PhpStorm that I should raise with them.
2. This is the expected behavior and it has just been fortunate that it worked the way I am trying to achieve for so long (`use App` *should* in fact be present for the inspector to understand what it is).
3. There is a trivial way either in the file structure, namespace usage or even PhpStorm settings to have it working the way it did before.

Comment: That's how 2016.1.x works, unfortunately. *I guess* it might be easier for IDE to analyse the code/resolve references this way .. but it also breaks some stuff, like advanced metadata (see latest comments) -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-31102 . It was sort of fixed (at least for actual function calls -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-30685 ) but as you can see it still has some side effects. I personally would recommend submitting a Bug Report (even if it will be marked as duplicate of another open ticket) .. just to get clear answer on this.

Comment: P.S. If you put FQN in `@return` (e.g. `@return \App`) in your function's PHPDoc -- will it work better?

Comment: @LazyOne Sigh and this is why I'm moving to TypeScript with Node. Thanks for the related links. Great idea I'll try it tonight!

Comment: @LazyOne Nope, no luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the behaviour has been corrected in a recent release (I just upgraded to `2016.1.2 Build #PS-154.1616`).